# Extracting values from spark RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

```
RDDData===RET
(
  12345,
  20170201,
  Map(12 -> 85, 15 -> 57, 00 -> 3, 09 -> 80, 21 -> 33, 03 -> 7, 18 -> 50, 06 -> 38, 17 -> 43, 23 -> 28, 11 -> 73, 05 -> 16, 14 -> 58, 08 -> 66, 20 -> 35, 02 -> 9, 01 -> 16, 22 -> 34, 16 -> 49, 19 -> 53, 10 -> 69, 04 -> 15, 13 -> 66, 07 -> 43),
  Map(12 -> 4, 15 -> 4, 00 -> 4, 09 -> 4, 21 -> 4, 03 -> 4, 18 -> 4, 06 -> 4, 17 -> 4, 23 -> 4, 11 -> 4, 05 -> 4, 14 -> 4, 08 -> 4, 20 -> 4, 02 -> 4, 01 -> 4, 22 -> 4, 16 -> 4, 19 -> 4, 10 -> 4, 04 -> 4, 13 -> 4, 07 -> 4),
  Map(12 -> 15, 15 -> 9, 00 -> 4, 09 -> 14, 21 -> 8, 03 -> 4, 18 -> 8, 06 -> 8, 17 -> 9, 23 -> 8, 11 -> 15, 05 -> 4, 14 -> 9, 08 -> 12, 20 -> 8, 02 -> 4, 01 -> 5, 22 -> 8, 16 -> 9, 19 -> 9, 10 -> 14, 04 -> 5, 13 -> 13, 07 -> 9)
)
```

I'm new to the spark and I don't know where to start. I have a rdd like mentioned above. Could you please help me to extract the values from the above RDD.

I want to extract the values and join the maps in 3rd, 4th and 5th columns based on key.

Thanks for the help

Comment: first impove the format of your question it is not understandable at all.

Comment: also please add expected output and attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try like this:

```
rdd.map{case(id, data, map3, map4, map5) => 
            map3.toList ++ map4.toList ++ map5.toList
       }
   .map(l => l.groupBy(_._1).map{case(k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2).toSeq)
```

First map function will retain only the maps converted to a list that concatenate all maps
The second map function will group by key and put all the values in a sequence.
So you will have your rdd containing only the maps, joined by key and as values a Seq of numbers (the ones that matches the keys from the maps)
The output should be :

```
(12 -> [85,4,15], 15 -> [57,4,9], 00 -> [3,4,4] .....
```

Comment: Why not give the output (or some of it) from the OP's example, so they can see if you've interpreted their (rather unclear) requirement correctly)?